# How to have tikzcd inside align?

Tags: align, tikz-cd, ampersand

With the `gathered` subsidiary environment, the code

```
\newcommand{\id}{\mathrm{id}}

\[\begin{gathered}
    \text{if $g$ is a left-inverse of $f$, then }
    \begin{tikzcd}
            A\ar[r, "f"]\ar[rr, "\id_A"', bend right = 30] & B\ar[r, "g"] & A
    \end{tikzcd}
    \text{ commutes; and,}\\
    \text{if $g$ is a right-inverse of $f$, then }
    \begin{tikzcd}
        B \ar[r, "g"]\ar[rr, "\id_B", bend right = 30] & A\ar[r, "f"] & B
    \end{tikzcd}
    \text{ commutes.}
\end{gathered}\]
```

produces:
[image]

Now, I wish to use align the sentences at the commutative diagrams. I try the following using the `align*` environment:

```
\begin{align*}
    \text{if $g$ is a left-inverse of $f$, then }
    & \begin{gathered}[c]
        \begin{tikzcd}
            A\ar[r, "f"]\ar[rr, "\id_A"', bend right = 30] & B\ar[r, "g"] & A
        \end{tikzcd}
    \end{gathered}
    \text{ commutes; and,}\\
    \text{if $g$ is a right-inverse of $f$, then } & 
    & \begin{tikzcd}
        B \ar[r, "g"]\ar[rr, "\id_B", bend right = 30] & A\ar[r, "f"] & B
    \end{tikzcd}
    \text{ commutes.}
\end{align*}
```

But the ampersands of `align*` and `tikzcd` seem to get mixed up. I get the following error messages:

1. Package pgf Error: Single ampersand used with wrong catcode.
   \end{align*}
2. Package pgf Error: No shape named `tikz@f@6-1-3' is
   known. I think the culprit is a tikzcd arrow in cell 1-1.
3. Package pgf Error: Single ampersand used with wrong catcode. \end{align*}
4. Package pgf Error: No shape named `tikz@f@7-1-3' is known. I think
   the culprit is a tikzcd arrow in cell 1-1.
5. Package pgf Error: Single
   ampersand used with wrong catcode. \end{align*}
6. Package pgf Error:
   No shape named `tikz@f@8-1-3' is known. I think the culprit is a
   tikzcd arrow in cell 1-1.
7. Package pgf Error: Single ampersand used
   with wrong catcode. \end{align*}
8. Package pgf Error: No shape named
   `tikz@f@9-1-3' is known. I think the culprit is a tikzcd arrow in
   cell 1-1. Overfull \hbox (66.04643pt too wide) detected

---

How can I get around this?

Comment: See section 3.4 in the `tikz-cd` manual. Inside `align` `&` has special meaning other than the one used in `tikzcd` so they clash.

Comment: I'm not sure what's the purpose of using `\[...\]` and `gathered` here. Or, worse, `align*`

Comment: why are you doing this in a math alignment? simply use a `tabular` or in fact I wouldn't align at all, and just use paragraphs.

Comment: @egreg I am using `align*` so that I the lower diagram is exactly below the upper one. And I used `gathered` so that I could break the first line after "and;". I couldn't use `\[...\]` here for this. And `\beging{tikzcd} ... \end{tikzcd}` will not be centered if I don't use a super-environment like `\[...\]`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks! `tabular` gave me what I wanted!

Comment: @Atom I can see no reason for aligning the two diagrams, which are similar but independent of one another. I added a simple trick for alignment in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mention @David Carlisle in his comment, use of simple table can be solution for your problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newcommand{\id}{\mathrm{id}}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
Suppose something about $f$ and $g$:

\begin{tabular}{@{} lcl @{}}
if $g$ is a left-inverse of $f$, then
    &   \begin{tikzcd}
     A\ar[r, "f"]\ar[rr, "\id_A"', bend right = 30] & B\ar[r, "g"] & A
        \end{tikzcd}    &   commutes;   \\
if $g$ is a right-inverse of $f$, then
    &   \begin{tikzcd}
    B \ar[r, "g"]\ar[rr, "\id_B"', bend right = 30] & A\ar[r, "f"] & B
        \end{tikzcd}    & commutes.
\end{tabular}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thank you very much! Sorry, I should wait with mine little  a bit ...

Comment: so long as egreg doesn't get the tick, all is well:-)

Answer (score 3):

You would need `ampersand replacement=\&` in the options to `\begin{tikzcd}` and `\&` instead of `&` for separating cells.

On the other hand, I can't see the need for a math display here: you want to present two facts (actually two implications), so use a list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\newcommand{\id}{\mathrm{id}}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
Suppose something about $f$ and $g$;
\begin{itemize}
\item if $g$ is a left-inverse of $f$, then
  $\begin{gathered}\begin{tikzcd}
     A\ar[r, "f"]\ar[rr, "\id_A"', bend right = 30] & B\ar[r, "g"] & A
  \end{tikzcd}\end{gathered}$
  commutes;

\item if $g$ is a right-inverse of $f$, then
  $\begin{gathered}\begin{tikzcd}
        B \ar[r, "g"]\ar[rr, "\id_B"', bend right = 30] & A\ar[r, "f"] & B
  \end{tikzcd}\end{gathered}$
  commutes.
\end{itemize}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It wouldn't be difficult to align the two diagrams, by measuring the words “left” and “right”:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\newcommand{\id}{\mathrm{id}}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
Suppose something about $f$ and $g$;
\begin{itemize}
\settowidth{\dimen0}{left}
\settowidth{\dimen2}{right}
\addtolength{\dimen2}{-\dimen0}

\item if $g$ is a left-inverse of $f$, then\hspace{\dimen2}
  $\begin{gathered}\begin{tikzcd}
     A\ar[r, "f"]\ar[rr, "\id_A"', bend right = 30] & B\ar[r, "g"] & A
  \end{tikzcd}\end{gathered}$
  commutes;

\item if $g$ is a right-inverse of $f$, then
  $\begin{gathered}\begin{tikzcd}
        B \ar[r, "g"]\ar[rr, "\id_B"', bend right = 30] & A\ar[r, "f"] & B
  \end{tikzcd}\end{gathered}$
  commutes.
\end{itemize}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I see no real reason for the alignment. To the contrary, having them in different positions underlines that they illustrate distinct properties.